# Pop up box with message from php file

Tags: javascript, php

I have been working on a php file and would like to display whether a file has been uploaded or not

I have tried:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file)) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('File sucessfully uploaded');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Upload failed');</script>";
}
```

But it is not producing a pop up. However I can see it in the developer options under response. Any idea how I can solve this please?

Comment: don't mix js and PHP! They execute differently and this can lead to unexpected behaviour. Just ajax it and popup the response

Comment: Is this a direct form submission - or are you using AJAX here?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to print `alert();` inside a `valid html`. See this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
Upload File: <input type="file" size="30" id="userfile" name="userfile">
<?php
$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/upload/";
if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) { 
  @mkdir($upload_dir, 0755, true);
}
if (isset($_FILES['userfile'])) {
  $temp_name = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
  $file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  $file_path = $upload_dir.$file_name;
}
if ((isset($_FILES['userfile'])) && (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))) {
  if (@move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $file_path)) {
    @chmod($file_path,0755);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('File sucessfully uploaded');</script>";
  } else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Upload failed');</script>";
  }
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This example works fine for me. I hope this helps.